# Find sum, average grouping by several fields using StreamAPI

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have class

```
public class CenterReportDto {
     ZonedDateTime date;
     int centerId;
     int amount;
     float percent;
}
```

and list of items

```
List<CenterReportDto> entityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried this

```
entityList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getDate().getMonth(),Collectors.summingInt(CenterReportDto::getAmount)))
         .forEach((s,j) -> System.out.println(s + "-" + j) );

entityList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getDate().getMonth(),
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(CenterReportDto::getPercent)))
                .forEach((s,j) -> System.out.println(s + "-" + j) );
```

and get

```
JANUARY-7
FEBRUARY-9

JANUARY-3.5
FEBRUARY-4.5
```

How to combine two methods and group by month and `centerId` to get sum of "amount" field  and average of "percent" field like :

```
JANUARY - 123 - 7 -  3.5
FEBRUARY -123 - 9 - 4.5
JANUARY - 456 - 7 -  3.5
FEBRUARY -456 - 9 - 4.5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Use [`YearMonth.from(item.getDate())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) to get a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object to group by. --- As for how to group and sum, you can find a gazillion examples with a simple web search.

Comment: see also https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-sum

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked :

```
   entityList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getDate().getMonth(),
                                         Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getCenterId(),
                                         Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                                                                      l -> {Integer sum = l.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i.getAmount()));
                                                                            Double avg = l.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(i -> i.getPercent()));
                                                                            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sum, avg);
                                                                            }))))
          .forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println(k.toString() + " - " + k1.toString() + " - " + v1.getKey() + " - " + v1.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 3):

It only calculates the sum because you use `Collectors.summingInt`. You could get a `IntSummaryStatistics` by `Collectors.summarizingInt` and <strike>calculate the average on your own</strike>. Oh, no, there is a handy [`IntSummaryStatistics#getAverage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getAverage()).

Comment: @harp1814 `Collectors.averagingDouble(CenterReportDto::getAmount))` loses `CenterReportDto` instances, because all it needs is `getAmount ` from them. To have the output like `"FEBRUARY -123 - 9 - 4.5"` the result of reduction should be a `CenterReportDto`, not a plain number